# Is there a proof of this multiset series summation identity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, mathematical-physics, statistical-mechanics

I found this identity online to help simplify the partition function of a harmonic oscillator system:

$$\sum^\infty_{\kappa=0}\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha+\kappa-1\\
\kappa
\end{pmatrix}z^\kappa=\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha},|z|\le1$$

I have searched the internet pretty extensively this morning and have not found any proof or justification for this identity. What is the justification for this identity?

Comment: Look up the generalized binomial theorem. That should help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams this is the technique I've been trying to use, but I can not figure out how the (x+y)^n in the binomial theorem turns into an (x-y)^n. I can see that I can make the x or y equal to 1, but i don't see how the sign flips to get the solution on the RHS above. Nor how the power in the RHS switches to negative to get our solution in the denominator.

Comment: What's the original source?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem). Supplant *n* by a continuous -α.